# Rounding only reals in an expression containing, reals, integers and symbols

Tags: programming, output-formatting, formatting

I am trying to make a function that would make rounding real numbers in an expression possibly consisting of real numbers, integer numbers and symbols. An example of such an expression is below:

```
expr = 1.2345 + 3.2471*x + 4.3946*x^2 + 5.56789*x^3 + 3.4812*x^4 + 
   1.34682*x*Exp[-2.3467*x^3] + 13.25684*x^3*Exp[23.9476*x^7] + 
   Sin[34.876459*x^2];
```

What I want to achieve is the following. Let us say, I would like to have all real numbers to have not more that two figures after comma. The expression then should then look as follows:

```
    1.23 + 3.25 x + 1.35 E^(-2.35 x^3) x + 4.39 x^2 + 5.57 x^3 + 
 13.26 E^(23.95 x^7) x^3 + 3.48 x^4 + Sin[34.88 x^2]
```

Such a function is useful, to show dynamically and in a compact form a result obtained in the course of dynamic calculation. For example, I often fit data to a function, the both being dependent upon parameter(s). To show the fitting function dynamically in the same Panel or Manipulate window I need to cut number of figures after comma of real numbers.

At present I am here:

```
    rnd[expr_, m_Integer] := 
  Map[If[NumberQ[#], 
     If[Element[#, Reals], (Round[#*10^m]/10^m // N), 
      IntegerPart[#]], #] &, expr, {1, Depth[expr]}];
```

Here expr is any expression to subject the rounding, m is the integer equal to the number of figures after comma to be left.

This function almost works. Its application to the expression given above yields the following:

```
rnd[expr, 2]

    (* 
1.23 + 3.25 x + 1.35 E^(-2.35 x^3.) x + 4.39 x^2. + 5.57 x^3. + 
     13.26 E^(23.95 x^7.) x^3. + 3.48 x^4. + Sin[34.88 x^2.] 
*)
```

You may see that the difference between what I get and what I want is that the powers are 2., 3. and so on instead of 2, 3 and so on. I cannot understand, why these decimal points show up, and how to get rid of them.

Comment: It seems this suits Your needs: `expr /. x_Real :> Round[x, .01]`

Comment: ...alternatively, `expr /. x_?InexactNumberQ :> Round[x, 0.01]`.

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, it indeed suits my need.

Comment: 0x4A4D Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards your final comment: "I cannot understand why these decimal points show up", and interested by your use of `Element`, it appears the integers are getting converted because they are found to be in the domain of real numbers, which I wouldn't have expected.

```
Element[1, Reals]
```

> True

So your function can be made to work thusly:

```
rnd[expr_, m_Integer] := Map[If[NumberQ[#],
    If[Element[#, Reals] && Not[Element[#, Integers]],
     (Round[#*10^m]/10^m // N), #], #] &, expr, {1, Depth[expr]}]
```

Comment: Succinctly put, `1` is real, but not `Real`, while `1.` is both real and `Real`. The "*Mathematica* sense" of `Real` (inexact number with zero imaginary part) versus the "mathematics sense" of real (any admissible element of $\mathbb R$), which `Element[]` tests for, are seen to be different.

Comment: @Chris Degnen Thank you.

Comment: @Chris, actually it is a useful comment